# What's the worst question you've ever seen on SF.com?

Tags: discussion

I thought it might be neat/funny to link to the worst questions you've ever seen on serverfault.

I'll start us off with https://serverfault.com/questions/209537/hi-can-any-ony-explain-elaborately-about-hosting-closed

Comment: Not really got any links, if only because there are too many to mention, but the questions that grind my teeth both here and in real life are the "do my homework/job for me" questions. Oh and in a slightly different sense, the junk that gets blindly migrated here from SO because people get as far as reading there's some kind of hardware involved and blindly click the vote to migrate button without really thinking about where to migrate to.

Comment: Whoah, have I just not been paying attention? When did you get mod status? Congrats.

Comment: I just spotted this monstrosity;

[http://serverfault.com/q/511441/1435][1]


  [1]: http://serverfault.com/q/511441/1435

Answer (score 5):

It's got to be [having a budget big enough for a server with 64Gb RAM, but wanting to run 32-bit Windows and SQL Server Express on it, and then bitching because Windows 64 bit apparently uses more memory when idle over 32-bit Windows, when in fac the idle footprint of Windows will change depending on how much memory SQL Server demands. I get frustrated just re-reading the damn conversation.](https://serverfault.com/questions/121658/60gb-of-memory-32-bit-os-and-pae-vs-64-bit-os).

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, these 2 questions (which are some of the most viewed on Server Fault) are awful.

- [The Coolest Server Names](https://serverfault.com/questions/45734)
- [Wiki: Irritating phrases you are subjected to in “the enterprise”](https://serverfault.com/questions/10043/wiki-irritating-phrases-you-are-subjected-to-in-the-enterprise)

I was thrilled when the coolest server names was closed .. now if only the irritating phrases would get closed so it doesn't keep rearing its ugly head every now and then.

Comment: Although I don't feel either question is exactly "on-topic", at +355/-7 for Names and +42/-2 for Phrases, I think the SF-community's opinion is quite undivided.

Comment: @jscott the coolest server names was acutally a SO question that got migrated when SF went live and accumulated most of it's votes there.

Comment: Well I'm game to vote for it to close again, questions like that are a waste of bits imo.

Comment: +1 Both those questions should have been closed immediately, instead of being fed with equally useless answers. BTW, the question being asked and answered here is no better.

Answer (score 3):

*The* worst? Not sure I've seen it yet. The questions I consider *most poor* are any of the step-by-step/spoon-feed-me/SendTehCodezPlz type questions. Especially when followed-up with combative commenting (from OP) and/or a general disregard for autodidactic/RTFM/Google.

*e.g.*, [What does ESXI server do](https://serverfault.com/questions/91537/what-does-esxi-server-do)

Comment: +1 "Spoon-feed-me" questions.. Doesn't the site say something about being for "Professionals"?

Answer (score 1):

I've seen some pretty bad ones. Most just glide into obscurity, rightfully ignored. But then there are some that are sneaky. They sound legitimate, or perhaps just enough off center that some judicious education can help. So I try. And they prove that they either fundamentally don't get it, or get combative about it.

- [Windows LocalSystem vs. System](https://serverfault.com/questions/168752/windows-localsystem-vs-system)

Case in point.

Then there are the ones that can only be answered by writing a text book. Those tend to get closed/deleted, so are hard to dig up. Except for a few. The converse to this kind of question are the ones that get actual [textbook-sized answers](https://serverfault.com/questions/49765/how-does-subnetting-work/49836#49836) that act as reference material for the rest of us.